# Using iText PdfCopy or PdfSmartCopy to assemble stamped pages leads to invalid PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am stamping a PDF form over and over using iText and trying to compile the resulting single page pdfs into a single pdf with many pages in RAM and return it in an http response.  An invalid PDF comes out no matter what I do.  If I do the same thing without the copy for a single page the PDF is perfect.  I've tried using PdfSmartCopy and PdfCopy, but the result is always invalid.  I think I am doing everything just as shown on the examples on the internet, but I must be missing something. Thanks for your suggestions!

```
ByteArrayOutputStream mainBaos;
PdfReader reader;
PdfStamper stamp;
AcroFields form;

OutputStream out = null;
try
{
    List<PrintableCheck> checks = service.getChecksToPrint();

    mainBaos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Document doc = new Document();
    PdfSmartCopy mainPDF = new PdfSmartCopy(doc, mainBaos);
    doc.open();

    for (PrintableCheck check : checks)
    {
        reader = new PdfReader(PDF_FILENAME);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);

        form = stamp.getAcroFields();

        form.setField("checkDate", check.getDate());
        form.setField("checkNumber", check.getNumber());
        form.setField("amountAlpha", check.getAmountAlpha());
        form.setField("amount", check.getAmount());
```

...

```
        stamp.setFormFlattening(true);
        stamp.close();
        reader.close();

        PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());
        PdfImportedPage page = mainPDF.getImportedPage(reader2, 1);
        mainPDF.addPage(page);
        mainPDF.freeReader(reader2);
        reader2.close();
    }

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setContentLength(mainBaos.size());
    response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
    response.addHeader("Content-Description", "File Transfer");
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=checks"
        + bank + "-" + DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date()) + ".pdf");
    response.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
    out = response.getOutputStream();
    doc.close();
    mainBaos.writeTo(out);
    out.flush();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    log.error("Failed to print checks", e);
}
finally
{
    if (out != null)
    {
        try
        {
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            log.error("Could not close output stream", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following line:

```
response.setContentLength(mainBaos.size());
```

You tell the response how many bytes you will send to the browser. However: at that moment, you don't know the exact size of the PDF, because you haven't closed the document yet.

You can solve your problem by moving the following line up:

```
doc.close();
```

This finalizes the document. Do not set the content length *before* this line.

Comment: Thanks so much for catching this master Lowagie.  You are the man!  I just upgraded from iText 2.1.1 to 5.5.3 and the upgrade was very painless.  Sorry to see your name go from the package.  The right thing to do, but you deserved the credit.

Comment: Thanks! It *was* the right thing to do, because there's a whole team behind iText now. It's no longer a one-or-two-man-project ;-)